# Upload files to sharepoint from Salesforce and access them from salesforce

Tags: integration

User uploads files in SalesForce. But it should actually save to SharePoint. User will not be knowing that, file is being saved in SharePoint and Only the Reference to the files will be in Salesforce.

After save, he can access all these files and when he clicks the file, it should pull the data from SharePoint and display it for him.

i have already gone through these links:
http://goldeninsights.com/2011/02/24/getting-sharepoint-to-talk-to-salesforce-on-the-cheap-part-1/#comment-6620

http://goldeninsights.com/2011/03/22/getting-sharepoint-to-talk-to-salesforce-on-the-cheap-part-ii/

But my client is not ready for this solutions as there seems to be no security.

Comment: Have you looked at Content as an alternative to SharePoint? It may not fit but it's not clear if you have looked it from your questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved it myself after a long research.
The solution is to get connected to SharePoint Online with OAuth and leverage the power of SharePoint 2013 REST APIs.
Features covered:

- Get authenticated
- Upload files with metadata
- Retrieve Files with metadata
- check permissions

I have put all of my effort results as posts on my blog. Below are the blog post links.

[SharePoint Online (O365) OAuth Authentication | Authorizing REST API calls against SharePoint Online Site | Get Access token from SharePoint Online | Set up OAuth for SharePoint Online Office 365](https://spshell.blogspot.com/2015/03/sharepoint-online-o365-oauth.html)

[Complete SharePoint 2013 REST API Reference](https://spshell.blogspot.com/2015/01/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-reference.html)

Comment: Were you able to send more than 6 Mb syncronously? Didnt you face heap size limit while making a REST call to Sharepoint API from Apex?

Comment: Were you able to upload files from salesforce?

Answer (score -2):

You can refer following link...

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_files_connect_overview.htm&language=en_US